# How to insert data in first form and update the same data in second form and so on

Tags: php, html, session

I want to ask, what if I want to insert data on first button click ( which is on the first page ) and then update the database with new fields on the rest forms.

Here is the index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<body>

 <div class="wrapperDiv">
    <form action="form-page2.php" method="post" id="form">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3" scope="row">
              <h3 style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">Form 1 </h3>
            <div align="center"></div></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">Name</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" class="required" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">Email</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" class="required" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">Mobile</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submitBtn1" id="submitBtn1" value="Next" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div><!-- end of .wrapperDiv -->

</body>
</html>
```

I inserted the data of first page in the second form which is done but now when user fill the second form the data should be updated in the same field. Second Page where I want to perform the update query:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn1'])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "";
    $database   = "phpmultipage";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if (!$conn) {
        die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        echo 'you are on';
    }

    $name   = $_POST['name'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

    $sql = "INSERT into detail (name,email,contact) VALUES ('$name','$email','$mobile')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo 'record added. Your ID:' . mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        echo $id;
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Form 2</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapperDiv">
    <form action="form-page3.php" method="post" id="form">
        <?php
        if(!isset($_POST['submitBtn1'])) header('location: index.php');
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submitBtn1') {
            ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
            <?php   
            }
        }
        ?>
        <table width="500">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3" scope="row"><h3>Form 2</h3></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">Password</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">Confirm Password</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submitBtn3" id="submitBtn3" value="Next" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And to perform this action I wrote this on page 3:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn3'])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $password   = "";
    $database   = "phpmultipage";

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if (!$con) {
        die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        echo 'you are on';

    }

    $password         = $_POST['password'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
    $sqli             = "UPDATE detail SET password='$password',cnf_pass='$confirm_password' WHERE user_id=$id";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sqli)) {
        echo 'record added';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Form 3 </title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapperDiv">
    <form action="process-complete.php" method="post" id="form">
        <?php
        if(!isset($_POST['submitBtn3'])) header('location: form-page2.php');
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submitBtn3') {
            ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
            <?php   
            }
        }
        ?>
        <table width="500">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="3" scope="row"><h3>Form 3</h3></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">City</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" value="" class="required" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">Street</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="street" value="" class="required" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><div align="right">District</div></th>
            <td><div align="center"><strong>:</strong></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="district" value="" class="required" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submitBtn2" id="submitBtn2" value="Save" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here $id shows as undefined variable.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: sir this code is only used on the local server and I already used mysqli_real_escape_string() there. Thanks for warning me I will post with full code.

Comment: It's a lot more work to call the escaping functions manually, and even then you're only one mistake away from serious trouble. These are extremely bad habits to get into, and fixing them is easy, *and* will save you a whole lot of debugging time in the future. There's no excuse for not doing it properly the first time when that's faster, easier, and more reliable than other methods.

Comment: Extremely sorry sir, I assure you I will not do this again. but currently, I want a solution of my problem.

Comment: There's an awful lot of code for us to try and read through, and the problem itself isn't described very clearly. Are you trying to make a multi-stage form which incrementally adds data to the same record?

Comment: Again Sorry sir! and yes this is what I want...this is a multi-stage form and I want to insert all data in the same record. But on first form submission, I want to provide them an id for future modification. I will be grateful if you help me.

Comment: The main problem is that I am a learner and have no one who suggests me. I am not in that condition to join an institute as well.

Comment: Generally you save the ID value you got from `last_insert_id` as a hidden field on the form, then use that to do an `UPDATE` on the next part of the form. There's a huge number of caveats here: You *must* verify that the ID is something created by the current user or someone could alter that and start changing arbitrary records in your database.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: you mean I have to put the code `<input type="hidden" name="new_id" value="<?php echo '$id' ?>" ` on form 3!!

Comment: Basically, yes, but be careful about trusting that value. It could be arbitrary. This is also where things like CSRF come into play, something frameworks will handle for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have got a solution.
With the help of `session` variable, I am able to move the `id` on each of my web pages.